# This webpage has a redirect loop in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with this strange behavior of *This webpage has a redirect loop*, I have a link in home page

```
<a href='<spring:url value="/url?view=offers" />'>offers</a>
```

and my controller is

```
@Controller
public class OfferController {

    @Autowired
    private OfferService offerService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showOffers(@RequestParam("view") String view, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("offers", offerService.findAll());
        return "redirect:/url?view=offers";
    }
}
```

this above code is causing the issue, what is wrong with above code.

Comment: redirect:/url?view=offers will call again the controller and this will go on again and again

Answer (score 1):

You have an /url URL mapping, and then after access /url, the code redirect it to /url?view=offers. That is the reason you get a redirect loop.

Maybe this is your purpose:

```
@Controller
public class OfferController {

    @Autowired
    private OfferService offerService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showOffers(@RequestParam(value = "view", defaultValue = "offers") String view, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("offers", offerService.findAll());
        return "url";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to do url rewriting, but couldn't be able to get that done.

Comment: any idea how to write my url as __www.host.com/url?view=offers__, any changes in `<a href='<spring:url value="/url?view=offers" />'>offers</a>` or in controller is highly appreciated in this case.

Comment: Actually i don't know what you mean, but i think you want redirect /url to /url?view=offers, but it got redirect loop.

Maybe you can add the default value of the parameter, try this:
`@RequestParam(value = "view", defaultValue = "offers") String view`
Then you get the same access from /url and /url?view=offers

Check the edited answer.

Comment: i think he wants to redirect to another domain www.host.com/url?view=offers from this controller domain